# Is it possible to create dynamic endpoint URLs?

Tags: url-rewriting, endpoints

I want to create an archive endpoint page that will have a dynamic slug, based on the taxonomy term slug.

e.g. If the taxonomy is Food and the current term is Onion, I want the endpoint slug to look like `onion-recipes`.

`www.domain.com/food/vegetables/onion/onion-recipes` Gives me a `404` even after flushing permalinks.

Code:

```
add_action( 'init', function() {
    $term = get_queried_object();
    $ep_slug = $term->slug.'-recipes';
    add_rewrite_endpoint( $ep_slug, EP_PAGES );
} );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`add_rewrite_endpoint()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_endpoint/) only supports ***static* endpoint names** like `trackback` and `recipes`, so if you need a *dynamic endpoint **name/slug***, then you would want to use [`add_rewrite_rule()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_rule/) instead.

And just so that you know, even if `add_rewrite_endpoint()` did support dynamic names/slugs, your code would not work because your function runs *too early* (via the `init` hook) and thus `get_queried_object()` would return a null, which means that `$term` is not actually an object (even if you were on a term archive page).

So for the `food/onion/onion-recipes` structure or endpoint, where `onion` is the *term slug*, you could use `add_rewrite_rule()` like so:

```php
add_action( 'init', function () {
    // Adds a rewrite rule for /food/<term slug>/<term slug>-recipes where "food"
    // here is a custom taxonomy.
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'food/(.+?)/([^/]+)-recipes/?$',
        'index.php?food=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
} );
```

Things to note:

1. `(.+?)` is a term slug or path which is read from the current URL *path*, and the slug could be `onion` or a "directory"/path like `onion/child` if your taxonomy is hierarchical.
2. `([^/]+)` is also a term slug, but without a `/` (slash). (I purposely put it in a group in case you'd need to access `$matches[2]`)
3. In the above regular expression (RegEx) pattern (which is the 1st parameter for `add_rewrite_rule()`), I used 2 capturing groups or subpatterns, and each group/subpattern match from the URL will be stored in an array named `$matches`.

   So if the current URL is `https://example.com/food/onion/child/child-recipes`, then `$matches[1]` is `onion/child`, whereas `$matches[2]` is `child`. I.e. `food/(onion/child)/(child)-recipes` — note the parentheses.

You can test and play with the above RegEx [here on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/YoYBDn/1).

Also, remember to flush the rewrite rules! Simply visit the Permalink Settings admin page.

### Update

If you want to create a *query var* for your endpoint, just like what `add_rewrite_endpoint()` does by default, and so that you can use [`get_query_var()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_query_var/) to retrieve the term slug from the endpoint name, you can use the [`query_vars` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/query_vars/) to register your query var.

Here's an example where the query var (name) is `food_recipe` (make sure the name is not already in use, e.g. by an existing post type or taxonomy):

```php
add_filter( 'query_vars', function ( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'food_recipe';
    return $vars;
} );
```

After that,

1. Change the rewrite rule's *query* (the 2nd parameter for `add_rewrite_rule()`) from `index.php?food=$matches[1]` to `index.php?food=$matches[1]&food_recipe=$matches[2]`
2. Then flush the rewrite rules, again. :)

And as for using `&food-info=recipes` in the above query, where `food-info` is a custom taxonomy name/slug, yes, you can. Any query args that `WP_Query` accepts, and even custom ones, can be used there, but whether the query would return any posts would of course depend on whether there are posts that matched the query. :)

Comment: PS: Sorry, I deleted my original answer.. but I hope this one helped you more. Also, as for using `recipes-with-onion` instead, just change the `([^/]+)-recipes` above to `recipes-with-([^/]+)` :)

Comment: Thanks this is perfect! Let's say "recipes" is a tax term of "food-info", can I simply change `index.php?food=$matches[1]` to `index.php?food=$matches[1]&food-info=recipes` to change the resulting query to only show posts attached to those 2 terms?

Comment: Additionally, it doesn't seem like I can use `get_query_var` with these dynamic slugs...

Comment: See the Update part in my revised answer, but I assumed that you only wanted to retrieve the term slug from the endpoint name? If you wanted to capture the entire endpoint name, then you can change the regex to `food/(.+?)/([^/]+-recipes)/?$`, then use `food_endpoint` as the query var, so change the query to `index.php?food=$matches[1]&food_endpoint=$matches[2]`, and of course, register the query var (`food_endpoint`).

Comment: Thanks @SallyCJ! It seems that if I'm at `domain.com/food/vegetables/onion-recipes`, the page works. It would be best if I was only able to access the `onion-recipes` page if I'm at `domain.com/food/vegetables/**onion**/onion-recipes`. Curious why this happens.

Comment: That is because `(.+?)` matches *anything* before the `/onion-recipes` part. So you really just need to play with the regex.. :) and if necessary, change the query (the `food=$matches[1]` part).

Comment: So for example, to match `vegetables/**onion**` only, i.e. `vegetables/<term slug>`, then (assuming your taxonomy is hierarchical), change the `(.+?)` to `(vegetables/[^/]+)` and then it will only match `vegetables/onion`, `vegetables/carrot`, `vegetables/green-bean`, etc, but not `vegetables/foo/bar` because `foo/bar` contains a slash. [Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/Lqq8Cd/1)

Comment: I'm starting to catch on, thank you. I don't necessarily need it to match the `vegetable` part, but rather the part of the url that comes right before the "endpoint page". Basically I only want `/onion-recipes` to work if the url preceding it is `/onion/`. If it's `/food/` or `/vegetables/`, it shouldn't work, as that will mess up the url structure. So should I just replace `(.+?)` with `([^/]+)`?

Comment: So you mean like `food/onion/onion-recipes` and `food/carrot/carrot-recipes` - note the "onion" and "carrot" in both paths - right? I.e. The two "onion" as in `onion/onion-recipes` must match, hence `carrot/onion-recipes` or `onion/carrot-recipes` should not work. If so, then I'm afraid the regex isn't able to control that. You need a PHP/WordPress solution.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm referring to. I also noticed that if I type in /food/totally-random-slug/here-too/283hsh/onion-recipes/ that it still shows the endpoint page, even though this should through a 404 because those pages in between don't exist. This could be a mess for SEO. Is there any way of preventing this with the current solution, or do we need a brand new solution?

Comment: @harvey Yes, and that's a limitation in the WordPress rewriting system - `add_rewrite_rule()` simply adds the rewrite rule. Same goes with `add_rewrite_endpoint()`, except that it also automatically creates a query var by default. Matters like checking whether the URL actually points to a valid resource (like a term that actually exists in the database) has to be handled manually, e.g. [via the `pre_handle_404` hook](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/393567). And btw, are you @Edegist?

Comment: @SallyCJ Thanks! The method you linked to looks like it should be the perfect fix, except since over here we are using the endpoint page, it will always throw a 404 because path of the current URL doesn't match the wp_query. (the wp_query on the endpoint page is `/food/onion/`, however the actual path is `/food/onion/onion-recipes/` so it doesn't match the queried object url. And yes that was me! I used a buddies computer and didn't realize I wasn't in my account ;)

Comment: I ended up using `preg_replace()` to remove the endpoints from the url.

Comment: Actually, you could still use the `pre_handle_404` hook to "cancel" requests to your endpoint page when the endpoint path is invalid (the term slug doesn't match), but the function/code in that linked answer should be used just as a reference (and not to be copy-pasted..). So for example, in your function, you could do something like `if ( $wp->query_vars['food_recipe'] !== $wp_query->get_queried_object()->slug ) { $wp_query->set_404(); }`. And would you mind sharing your `preg_replace()` code? (as a comment, and I just wanted to understand what you meant by "remove the endpoints")

Comment: ( Sorry for the late reply.. :) ) (this is just a temporary comment)