# tax_query in pre_get_posts

Tags: wp-query, pre-get-posts

I'm trying to add a tax_query for the query of a custom post type single page with this code.

```php
function wcua_pre_get_posts ($query) {
    // Also removed this condition
    if( is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() ) {
        return;
    }

    $contest = get_query_var('contest');
    
    if( ! empty($contest) ) {
        $query->set('tax_query', [
            [
                'taxonomy' => 'contest',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => [$contest], // Also sent it as a string and removed the operator
                'operator' => 'IN'
            ]
        ]);
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'wcua_pre_get_posts');
```

But it does not work. The result is not filtered. To test that it reaches that condition, I added a breakpoint and it does but the result is not filtered. Besides that I also added another thing `$query->set('post__not_in', [1])` just to test and it does appear in the query, and the result does not change but I know the query changes.

I searched on the whole site and there are a few hooks for pre_get_posts but nont alter the tax_query. Also change the priority to 10k.

This is the register_taxonomy code for the custom post type

```
register_taxonomy('contest', 'entry', [
    'hierarchical'          => true,
    'labels'                => [
        'name'                       => _x( 'Contests', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name'              => _x( 'Contest', 'taxonomy singular name' )
    ],
    'show_ui'               => true,
    'show_admin_column'     => true,
    'query_var'             => true,
    'publicly_queryable'    => true,
    'rewrite'               => array( 'slug' => 'contest' )
]);

// Doing a rewrite rule for the CPT 
add_rewrite_rule('^([a-z-]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-z]+)/?', 'index.php?post_type=entry&contest=$matches[1]&contest_year=$matches[2]&name=$matches[3]', 'top');
add_rewrite_tag('%contest_year%', '([0-9]+)va');

// Query vars are set
```

Printed the $wp_query to see what it has and I see the `tax_query` in the `query_vars` array with what I added, but the `tax_query` property is NULL.

```
add_action('the_post', function() {
    global $wp_query; 
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($wp_query);
    echo '</pre>';
});
```

What could I be doing wrong? Did I forget something? Queries for CPT individual pages can't be changed?

Comment: "*custom post type single page*" and "*CPT individual pages*" - why would you add a taxonomy query to the main query on single post pages? What were you really trying to do?

Comment: If i go to `/contest-that-exists/2022/name-of-artist` and `/contest-that-does-not-exist/2022/name-of-artist`, both work and throws the same entry (a picture of their art). But the artist could submit different art different years. I could filter the year, and that works but the first part of the url would still work even if the contest of the name does not exist. 
 
I guess another approach could be just to throw a 404 if the first part is not found in some other hook.

Comment: What you said makes sense and I thought about it but wasn't sure because  I watched this video where they added a meta_query and thought that a tax_query could be applied as well. https://youtu.be/ECFVrBoQYRw?t=2142

Comment: So you are basically trying to disable the latter URL (`/contest-that-does-not-exist/...`), right? And unfortunately, that happens because as long as the post name/slug is good, then WordPress will load the correct post page. The good side, though, is that if one didn't remember the full URL, then only by knowing the post slug, would help the user land on the correct page. And yes, you can disable it by issuing a 404 error, and in fact, there's an example [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/393567/137402) for taxonomy terms.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Ended up doing something weird: on `save_post` I save the uri part (/contest/year/artist-name) as  `entry_path` on the postmeta table and then on `pre_get_posts` I put the `meta_query` to filter by `entry_path` (building the uri). It also throws 404. I don't like this solution but until I read more the wp core code, it is enough.

Comment: Well.. Using the approach in that linked answer (which in your case would be to compare the current URL with the actual post permalink), would have been (much) easier... Plus meta queries can make your site *runs very slow* (depending on how large your dataset is), so you've actually picked the ***least preferred*** workaround 

Comment: Ah! Forgot to say there will be multiple contests and one person can participate in multiple in the same year. So it handles that and also handles the 404..Not a large dataset, not the prefered workaround but that's what I could came up with. And there is w3 total cache

Comment: I appreciated your efforts in coming up with that workaround, but if you had asked for an example (using the `pre_handle_404` filter), I would be more than happy to write one for you.. :)